# Installing Maven Artifacts Into a Local Repository From Outside Of Any Project

Tags: java, maven, package-managers

Is there any way to install an arbitrary Maven artifact into your local repository without first creating and switching to a project and specifying that package as one of its dependencies?

Comment: For context, I'm trying to install OpenJFX 11 system-wide.

Comment: You can simply just download the artifact and copy/move it to the local repository manually.

Comment: @t0mppa:  Would Maven pick that up properly later, though?

Comment: On another note, I think I could, alternatively to the only answer yet given below, use `mvn dependency:get` somehow, but I haven't quite gotten that to work yet…  (I keep getting `PluginResolutionException`s…which _might_ be understandable, since the package I'm looking for might not be stored on Maven Central in quite the standard format…, but _that_ part is sort of orthogonal here.)

Comment: If it's in the right path, Maven will pick it up automatically. However, what exactly are you trying to do? Sounds like you want to automatically populate your local repository with artifacts that you may or may not use later as project dependencies. What's the end game there?

Comment: @t0mppa:  I want to have an Oracle Java installation that's as nearly as complete as compared to the one I had before I upgraded to Java 11 as possible, as that version no longer ships some components that were previously available in Oracle's Java distribution.  JavaFX is one of these, and is available through Maven via OpenJFX.  After fixing all of this, I will handle future Maven dependencies traditionally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you have the jar file of the artifact that you want to install to your local repository, you can the run the below command from your command prompt or terminal. Replace the value inside the angle brackets to your desired ones. And then you can use this as a dependency in your Maven projects.

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id> -DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=<packaging>
```

HTH

Comment: So there's no way to do this entirely from within Maven itself such that you can later tell it to update a package installed separately from its later use, then?

Comment: Never mind; see [a comment I left on my original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52637871/installing-maven-artifacts-into-a-local-repository-from-outside-of-any-project#comment92278970_52637871) for a way I found that would let me do that.  I've backed off from that approach and returned to this one, though, since it fits better with how I manage packages on my system.